# Unable to install pod, when upgrade the react-native version from 0.63.0 to 0.68.0

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

I have upgrade the react-native version from 0.63.0 to 0.68.0. when I'm trying to install pod, it's not installing. throug an error: -
Project has been deintegrated. No traces of CocoaPods left in project.
Note: The workspace referencing the Pods project still remains.
Auto-linking React Native modules for target TestApp: BVLinearGradient, RNAppleAuthentication, RNCAsyncStorage, RNCMaskedView, RNDeviceInfo, RNFS, RNFileViewer, RNImageCropPicker, RNImageToPdf, RNReanimated, RNScreens, RNSentry, RNShare, RNVectorIcons, ReactNativeLocalization, react-native-date-picker, react-native-fbsdk, react-native-geolocation, react-native-geolocation-service, react-native-google-places, react-native-maps, react-native-netinfo, react-native-restart, react-native-safe-area-context, react-native-splash-screen, react-native-video, react-native-view-shot, react-native-webview, and rn-fetch-blob
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for DoubleConversion from ../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec
[Codegen] Found FBReactNativeSpec
/Users/avineshkumarsingh/Desktop/App/TestApp/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods_utils/script_phases.rb:50: warning: Passing safe_level with the 2nd argument of ERB.new is deprecated. Do not use it, and specify other arguments as keyword arguments.
/Users/avineshkumarsingh/Desktop/App/TestApp/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods_utils/script_phases.rb:50: warning: Passing trim_mode with the 3rd argument of ERB.new is deprecated. Use keyword argument like ERB.new(str, trim_mode: ...) instead.
Fetching podspec for Folly from ../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec
―― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
Error:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=relative+URI%3A+%2FUsers%2Favineshkumarsingh%2FDesktop%2FTestApp%2FTestAppo%2Fnode_modules%2Freact-native%2Fthird-party-podspecs%2FFolly.podspec&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
Found no similar issues. To create a new issue, please visit:
https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/issues/new

here is my podfile:-
platform :ios, '11.0'

require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'TestApp' do

pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 6.13.0'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/React/FBReactNativeSpec"
pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
pod 'React-callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/callinvoker"
pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec',:modular_headers => false
pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec',:modular_headers => false

pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'
pod 'RNGestureHandler', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler'

pod 'RNPermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'
permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'

pod 'Permission-LocationWhenInUse', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationWhenInUse.podspec"
pod 'Permission-LocationAlways', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationAlways.podspec"
pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera.podspec"
pod 'Permission-MediaLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/MediaLibrary.podspec"
pod 'Permission-PhotoLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/PhotoLibrary.podspec"

pod 'RNFirebase', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios'

target 'TestAppTests' do
inherit! :search_paths
end

use_native_modules!
end

target 'TestApp-tvOS' do

target 'TestApp-tvOSTests' do
inherit! :search_paths
end

end

How can I resolve this issue, what are chanegs require for 0.68.0 which is useful for installing the pods.